# Ways to approximate multiple samples of same function in R

Tags: r, least-squares, approximation

Example dataset (simplified):

```
set.seed(42)
t = seq(0,10,0.1)
y = sapply(1:10,function(x){return(sin(t)+runif(101,min=-0.1,max=0.1))})
matplot(data.frame(y), pch=1, col=1)
```

So I've got 10 (~3000 in my real case) sample records of the same function and I'd like to approximate that. Fortunately the `y-values` in my real case are evenly spaced as well. In fact it's a time series.

My first idea was to take the mean like that:

```
approximate = apply(y,1,mean)
```

Which seems to work fine in the example and probably is sufficient for my purposes. However, I'm not sure it's the best way for my real case, since the sample isn't uniformly distributed at each point in time but biased. Also that bias varies over time. Therefore I thought a least squares-approximation might be best. I'm not sure though and haven't found an implementation for my purpose yet (`stats::nls` was close but I understand that you need to provide the true function which I don't know).

`(Edit)` The purpose of it all: afterwards I want to find out which samples deviate the most from the approximation (that I interpret as the 'ideal' time series). I'm interested in the deviation over the entire time series (by comparing the mean of each sample with the approximation's mean) and also in samples that contain outlier intervals.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "y-values are evenly spaced" and "the sample isn't uniformly distributed in time"? I can't make sense out of that in combination with your sample data, which has a random component in `y` (not `t`).

Comment: 1) If you'd `plot(t,y[,1])` then all points are evenly spaced (because `t` is a sequence). For the sake of argument we can say each sample is one-dimensional. 2) For each point in time I have 3000 sample values (for my real data set). Those are not necessarily uniformly distributed around the mean at each point in time. 3) The random component in my sample is uniformly distributed but in my real case it is not (in fact I don't know what distribution it is). I added it, so that I can produce 10 different samples.

Comment: OK. Do you know if the underlying function is expected to be repetitive?

Comment: If by repetitive you mean it repeats itself like the sin-function, then no. I just chose the sin-function to generate sample data, but it could as well be the function `x = y`. The word function may be misleading for my real dataset; it's just a sequence of numbers recorded during a production process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already said: as you don't have information about details of the random component in your signal as well as about the signal itself, this will in the end most likely boil down to using something like `mean` or `median` for all values available at each `t`, which will give you the mean/median signal - then using those values to reconstruct your signal. The assumption you do with this is that your noise would be unbiased (which is not the case), so your basis for reconstructing your signal will be (slightly) biased as well. From there you could go on with regular tools.

In case of doubt I'd probably try multiple approaches and compare their findings, then think about if they actually support my intuition/knowledge about the problem domain - and if yes, I'd probably accept them as they are.

Comment: Good answer, steered me in the right direction of thinking about the problem, i.e. aligning the estimator to the distribution at each `t`. Since that distribution is unknown and the bias varies with each `t` and there are several thousand `t`s I'm going with your last suggestion of benchmarking multiple approaches. (Also, stupid me just remembered that least-squares and mean are one and the same in my 1-dimensional case).